# Почему запрос выполняется два раза?

Tags: php, mysql

Здравствуйте. Хочу сделать что бы при переходе на страничку, добавлялся +1 просмотр к ней.

```
$coll_look = $option['look']+1; //кол-во уже имеющихся просмотров + 1

mysql_query("UPDATE `page` SET `look` = '$coll_look' WHERE `id` = '$option[id]' LIMIT 1");
```

В итоге добавляет +2 почему то.

А если код сделать так:

```
$coll_look = $option['look']+1; //кол-во уже имеющихся просмотров + 1

echo "Тут написать любой текст";

mysql_query("UPDATE `page` SET `look` = '$coll_look' WHERE `id` = '$option[id]' LIMIT 1");
```

Добавит +1 как и нужно.

В чем может быть дело?

Comment: А фиг его знает. Вставь костыль `echo "";`)

Comment: @Yuri не помогло. Все равно +2

Comment: Варианта три: 1) $option['look'] инкрементируется еще где-то выше 2) код инклудится два раза 3) страница вызывается два раза.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Логично предположить, что к странице происходит два обращения, просто вы об этом не знаете. Такое бывает, например, если в системе используется "единая точка входа" для всех ЧПУ адресов, а какой-то из подключаемых ресурсов отсутствует. В итоге вместо, скажем, favicon.ico, браузер получает снова ваш index.php

Узнать это наверняка можно заглянув в access.log вашего вебсервера.

Answer (score 0):

Во-первых, лучше использовать mysqli, а во-вторых попробуйте такой простой запрос сделать:

```
$mysqli->query("UPDATE page SET look = look + 1 WHERE id = $option[id] LIMIT 1")
```

Comment: Я использую `mysql` для соединения с базой. поэтому этот запрос у меня не работает.

Comment: Ну замените просто текст запроса на тот что я предложил. И еще не совсем понятно зачем вы используете LIMIT если id должен однозначно идентифицировать запись. И да, mysql_(драйвер) и функции считаются устаревшими.

Comment: заменил. **mysql_query("UPDATE page SET look = look + 1 WHERE id = $option[id]");** - все равно + 2

Comment: Может страница дважды вызывается?

Comment: да нет, просто обычная страница, никаких переадресаций и прочего там нет

Comment: выложите полный код странички, так проще будет

Comment: И покажите скриншот chrome Developer Tools, вкладка Network, с включенным preserve log. А лучше screencast.